# Are finitely generated subgroups of $PSL_n(\mathbb{R})$ linear?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Can finitely generated subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ necessarily be embedded into $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  In particular, I would like a linear representation for the fundamental group of a closed orientable surface of genus greater than or equal to 2 (which we can naturally embed in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ by viewing the surface as a quotient of the hyperbolic plane by a certain group of isometries).

Comment: Are you familiar with the adjoint representation?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I am not familiar with the adjoint representation.  Is it what user392576 below mentioned?

Comment: user392576's representation is closely related to the adjoint representation. The thing is that $G=PSL(n,R)$ is a Lie group and its action on   itself via conjugation fixes the neutral element $e$. Hence, by looking at the differentials we obtain a linear representation of $G$ on the tangent space $T_eG$ (the Lie algebra of $G$). This is called the "adjoint representation". Its kernel is exactly the center of $G$ which is trivial, hence, $G$ (as any centerless connected Lie group) has a faithful linear representation. Concretely, $T_eG$ in your case is the

Comment: ... vector space of skew symmetric traceless $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and the action is via "conjugation": $A\mapsto g A g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ itself is a linear group: there is a smooth representation $$\rho : PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow GL(\mathbb{R}^3)$$ defined by $$\rho(A)(x,y,z) = (x',y',z')$$ where $$\begin{pmatrix} x' & y' \\ y' & z' \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{pmatrix} A^T.$$ As $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is simple this map must be an embedding.

Comment: Thanks, where does this representation "come from"?